# Data cannot be inserted when geographic location is negative in NebulaGraph Database

Tags: nebula-graph

Some basic information are as follows:

- NebulaGraph version is 3.2.1.
- Deployment way is distributed.
- Installation way is RPM.
- Disk is non-SSD.
- CPU and memory information is Single node 4core8g.

My problem is like this:

When I import data using importer, there is the following TAG definition:

```
CREATE TAG location(geo geography(point));
```

When I insert the following data, it shows fine

```
INSERT VERTEX `location`(`geo`) VALUES  "117.201244-31.956496": (ST_GeogFromText("Point(117.201244 31.956496)"))
```

The problem occurs when I insert data with negative geographic locations

```
INSERT VERTEX `location`(`geo`) VALUES  "-361.000000--361.000000": (ST_GeogFromText("Point(-361.000000 -361.000000)"))
```

[image]
As far as I know, geographic locations can be negative. Why does this problem happen? Does nebula not support data with negative geographic locations?

Answer (score 0):

NebulaGraph certainly supports the negative geographic locations. However, there is a range limitation (±180, ±90).

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula/blob/6898ebb10f4f5b09604704790e5cfd65f75d7083/src/common/datatypes/Geography.cpp#L61-L69). You can have a second try.